# flutter Call sequence of onTab function on ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying with https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/startup_namer/step6_add_interactivity/lib/main.dart everything works fine but 
when i keep debugging point in the onTab function( At line number 61) and breakpoint in ListView.Builder( At line number 38 ).
OnTab method is getting called first after that only ListView is getting called but i'm not able to understand how the index are correctly calculated in onTap method because th actual logic for index is placed at ListView.

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOdh9.png)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return const Divider();

        final index = i ~/ 2;
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }
    final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(_suggestions[index]);
```

[OnTap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQeSx.png)

```
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      if (alreadySaved) {
        _saved.remove(_suggestions[index]);
      } else {
        _saved.add(_suggestions[index]);
      }
    });
```

Please explain how the index is getting calculated onTap.

Answer (score 1):

The favorite item is storing Set.

```dart
 final _saved = <WordPair>{};
```

Once you click on favorite button, it checks whether it is already on `_saved`

```dart
final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(_suggestions[index]);
```

Now if `alreadySaved` is true, it remove from the current tap item from the set.

```dart
if (alreadySaved) {
  _saved.remove(_suggestions[index]);
}
```

If it `alreadySaved` is false mean , `_saved` doesnt contain the item, it add it.

```
 else {
  _saved.add(_suggestions[index]);
}
```

> It is not storing the index, it is storing items value

And `_suggestions` is holding all generated item.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply and sorry if my question was not clear. I understand this adding and removing of values in the List. My exact question is onclick of fav i con onTap method is getting called immediately , I'm just wondering how the value of index is correctly coming without going on line number { final index = i ~/ 2; }. Keep break point on index calculation and onTap function and explain how the index is getting calculated.

Comment: for odd number it is returning divider instead of ListTile  `i ~/ 2` is known as integer division, here  the i will get half and set as index, actual index of item is (around)half,  Also on the same manner it saving on `_suggestions`, therefore index is working properly, you can include a print statement on ontap to check the value or adding breakPoint on debug mode.  `onTap:(){  print("i $i index :$index"); ...`

Comment: As you suggested i have added the print statement for logging the index value.                                                              I/flutter ( 1080): The value of index after on Tab: 2
I/flutter ( 1080): The value of Index in ListView: 0
I/flutter ( 1080): The value of Index in ListView: 1
I/flutter ( 1080): The value of Index in ListView: 2
I/flutter ( 1080): The value of Index in ListView: 3
I'm expecting first the ListView should be called before onTap. But onTap is getting called first but the logic for the index is there in ListView section only.

Answer (score 0):

variable  "index" is under the scope of Item builder and ListView and its onTap function can access the variable from its stack memory.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/